# Flash Socket Policy File

Tags: flash, sockets, cross-domain-policy

I've been working with Flash sockets and have a server setup in C/Linux. I am having trouble getting through the policy file request part. I've seen the other posts on SO and checked Adobe's site but I'm still having some problems.

On my server after I accept a connection I get the `<policy-file-request/>.` I'm using the following XML policy file.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.adobe.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
<allow-access-from domain="*" to-ports="*"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

I just put the whole file into a char array and then write it out through the same port that I got the request (I'm not using 843 but a custom port). I've read that it is suppose to end with a zero byte (does this mean NULL or '\0' ?). I can't seem to get past this part.

On my client side I have a socket event listener such as

```
sock.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.SOCKET_DATA, sockFunc);
```

but the event is never firing.

To compound the problem, Chrome doesn't seem to like me using Flash debug and when I use IE or FF my server just blocks on recv and never gets the `<policy-file-request/>`. I'm guessing that on IE and FF it tries port 843 and then just gives up? Is it bad practice to try to send the policy file through a custom port?

Any help would really be appreciated. I'm really stuck here :(

EDIT:
With adding a zero byte to the end my server now accepts the connection, reads the policy request, writes the policy file across the socket, then accepts again and blocks on recv. Accept should be blocking since I'm only trying to connect the one client right now. Is the client suppose to reconnect with a new file descriptor after the policy file is correctly received? On the client I'm trying to write to the server with

```
sock.writeUTFBytes("Hello");
sock.flush();
```

but it's obviously never making it there since recv is blocking.

Comment: NULL is not a byte. They mean an actual zero byte. (What you get if you do `printf("%c", 0)` in C.)

Comment: I tried sending the XML with an appending 0 such as <?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.adobe.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
<allow-access-from domain="*" to-ports="*"/>
</cross-domain-policy>0 and it's still doing the same

Comment: That's not a zero byte. We mean the *number* zero, not the digit `0`, which is a 48.